# Perl Text::CSV_XS treats comment as data when it is the last line

Tags: csv, perl, xs

I wonder if this is a bug or feature of `Text::CSV_XS`. When the last line in my CSV is a comment, it will be parsed as a line containing data (yielding undef or ""). How to repodruce:

```
$ cat test.csv
id | name
#
42 | foo
#
```

This is my perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use strict;

use Text::CSV_XS qw(csv);
use Data::Dumper;

# Returns array of hashrefs for argument CSV file.
sub load_csv_file {
  my $filename = shift;
  return csv (
    in               => $filename,
    sep_char         => '|',
    headers          => 'auto',
    allow_whitespace => 1,
    comment_str      => "#"
  );
}
my $table = load_csv_file("test.csv");
print Dumper($table);
```

When run it dumps this:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'id' => '42',
            'name' => 'foo'
          },
          {
            'id' => '',             # WHY IS THIS ENTRY HERE?
            'name' => undef
          }
        ];
```

I would have expected the last line to be treated as a comment and ignored.
When I remove the comment in the last line from test.csv, I get what I expect, just one row:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'id' => '42',
            'name' => 'foo'
          }
        ];
```

What am I missing? I'm using Text::CSV_XS version 1.47 on Ubuntu Jammy.

Comment: @toolic, OK reported on rt.cpan.org with bug ID #150501: Perl Text::CSV_XS treats comment as data when it is the last line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reporting, this was fixed in version 1.53, Changelog entry

```
1.53    - 2023-11-22, H.Merijn Brand
    * Two casts for -Wformat (issue 50)
    * Add --skip-empty to csv2xlsx
    * Add --font and --font-size to csv2xlsx
    * Fix skip_empty_rows ("skip") and trailing newlines (Corey Hickey, PR#52)
    * Fix comment in last line (RT#150501)
```